# Override an inline CSS style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter's typeahead script to autosuggest with my search form. However, the script generates its own CSS styles, which I can't seem to override. You can see the problem here: http://bahcalculator.org/dev/nano.php. I tried to create a copy of the style .tt-hint within my style sheet, but the inline style is overriding it. How can I make .tt-hint inherit the styles from my form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using CSS you have no choice but to use an [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) rule for each declaration within the `.twitter-typeahead .tt-hint` selector as there is no other way to override the inline styles using an external stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the styles using JavaScript, which will *replace* the inline style or you can use the `!important` keyword in your CSS, which will *overwrite* inline styles:

```
div.uk-form-row > span.twitter-typeahead {
    position: absolute !important;
}
```